# How is an address beginning with a 3 valid?

Tags: address

The Bitcoin Dark Wallet project is accepting donations to address [32wRDBezxnazSBxMrMqLWqD1ajwEqnDnMc](https://blockchain.info/address/32wRDBezxnazSBxMrMqLWqD1ajwEqnDnMc). How is this a valid address? I thought that all Bitcoin public addresses start with `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [List of address prefixes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes), an address beginning with `3` is *Bitcoin script hash*. This means that transactions sent to this address are handled differently than normal transactions.